# Excel prompt user for number to use in macro

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I have a recorded macro to pull select fields from a web service, the URL is something like http://xxxx.com/reportviewer.aspx?ids=**123456789012** 
I would like to prompt the user to input that number as a variable and have the number be passed to the 2 locations were that number is used in the macro.

I know that i have to create another macro to have the user input a value for after that I'm unsure of how pass that along to be filled in the correct location?

Here is my code so far

```
Sub Macro2()
 '
' Macro2 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+r
'
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "URL;http://xxxx.com/reportviewer.aspx?ids=123456789012", _
        Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
        .Name = "reportviewer.aspx?ids=123456789012"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
        .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
        .WebTables = "30,33,37,38,46"
        .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
        .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
        .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
        .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
        .WebDisableRedirections = False
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
    Range("A2").Select
```

Comment: Can't the user just type the number into a cell on the spreadsheet before you execute the macro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `InputBox` to collect the user's input.
After collecting, you can test their input before continuing to execute the code.
here's the input/validation example:

```
'-store user input in 'sUserInput' variable
Dim sUserInput As String
sUserInput = InputBox("Enter Number:", "Collect User Input")

'test input before continuing to validate the input
If Not (Len(sUserInput) > 0 And IsNumeric(sUserInput)) Then
    MsgBox "Input not valid, code aborted.", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Your code can reference the variable by refering to the `sUserInput` here's a complete version:

```
Sub Macro2()
 '
' Macro2 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+r
'
    '-store user input in 'sUserInput' variable
    Dim sUserInput As String
    sUserInput = InputBox("Enter Number:", "Collect User Input")

    'test input before continuing to validate the input
    If Not (Len(sUserInput) > 0 And IsNumeric(sUserInput)) Then
        MsgBox "Input not valid, code aborted.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If

    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "URL;http://network.construction.com/reportviewer.aspx?ids=" & sUserInput, _
        Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
        .Name = "reportviewer.aspx?ids=" & sUserInput
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
        .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
        .WebTables = "30,33,37,38,46"
        .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
        .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
        .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
        .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
        .WebDisableRedirections = False
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow thank you this would have taken me forever to realize that you could use sUserInput

Comment: Yeah. in VBA you can always join two strings together with the `&` symbol. This is super-useful when one of those strings is a variable!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily

```
Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+r
'

    Dim stpo
       stpo = InputBox("Enter the report number")
     With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
            "URL;http://network.construction.com/reportviewer.aspx?ids="&stpo, _
            Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
```